# Google Translate

Tags: c#, google-translate

Отправлял запросы на `https://translate.google.ru/translate_a/single`, чтобы переводить текст. В последние дни функция перевода перестала работать.
Проблема в GET-параметре `tk`. Ранее передавал произвольное значение, и все было в порядке. А сейчас, похоже, в `tk` как-то кодируется сам текст для перевода.
Например, для `q=b` вроде бы всегда передается `tk=192302.313611`

Может кто-то помочь разобраться, как формируется `tk` параметр в Google Translate
ли подсказать реально работающий на данный момент пример переводчика на C#?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Алгоритм и всестороннее обсуждение проблемы можно найти здесь [здесь](https://github.com/Stichoza/google-translate-php/issues/32).

Там же есть примеры реализации для нескольких языков: [Python](https://github.com/Stichoza/google-translate-php/issues/32#issuecomment-246770142), [Java](https://github.com/Stichoza/google-translate-php/issues/32#issuecomment-231959218), [JavaScript](https://github.com/Stichoza/google-translate-php/issues/32#issuecomment-229833429).

На C# реализации нет, придётся самому писать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.